# Is there such a CSS framework?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-frameworks

I'm searching for a CSS framework that is responsive, large (more than 1000px), and where I can do the folowing :

Large design :

[image: large design]

Normal design :

[image: normal design]

Mobile design :

[image: mobile design]

Any suggestions ? I have tried [960.gs](http://960.gs/), [Titan framework](http://titanthemes.com/titan-framework-a-css-framework-for-responsive-web-designs), [1140 css grid](http://cssgrid.net/), and the [Golden Grid System](http://goldengridsystem.com/), but I'm not sure I can do everything I want in any of them.

Comment: is there a special reason why it must be a framework and you can't make a tailored solution?

Comment: http://getskeleton.com/, http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: Not really.. I'm just new to grid systems and wanted to use something that's already in use and polished

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to serve different css by detecting the screen size.

This tool does it: [Adapt.js](http://adapt.960.gs/) (Take a look at [Less](http://lesscss.org/) too)

With Adapt.js you can do stuff like this:

```
// Edit to suit your needs.
var ADAPT_CONFIG = {
  // Where is your CSS?
  path: 'assets/css/',

  // false = Only run once, when page first loads.
  // true = Change on window resize and page tilt.
  dynamic: true,

  // Optional callback... myCallback(i, width)
  callback: myCallback,

  // First range entry is the minimum.
  // Last range entry is the maximum.
  // Separate ranges by "to" keyword.
  range: [
    '0px    to 760px  = mobile.css',
    '760px  to 980px  = 720.css',
    '980px  to 1280px = 960.css',
    '1280px to 1600px = 1200.css',
    '1600px to 1920px = 1560.css',
    '1940px to 2540px = 1920.css',
    '2540px           = 2520.css'
  ]
};
```

Comment: what about bootstrap? though not sure if it is only responsive up to 940px? worth a look though

Comment: Yeah I bootstrap is not wide enough

Comment: I will try doing it without a framework and/or using Adapt.js

Answer (score 4):

ooh what you need is Css3 media queries..

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/CSS3MediaQueries/

Check the link